# Django queries Especial Characters

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, sqlite

I Working on location from google maps and using django to. My question is:

I have a String in `request.GET['descricao']` lets say it contains "Via rapida".

In my database i have store = "Via Rápida"  i'm doing :

```
local = Local.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.GET['descricao'])
```

with that i can get everthing fine like "Via Rapida" but the result that have "Via rápida" never get match in the query (ASCI character may be?)

what must i do given a string "Via rapida" match "via rápida" and "via rapida"? Regular Expressions? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better way is to use a [Full Text search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search) engine , Here is a list of Full Text search engine that can be used with django :

- [Sphinx](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx)
- [whoosh](http://whoosh.ca/)
- [Djapian (Xapian)](http://code.google.com/p/djapian/)

And wee shouldn't forget [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) which is a proxy that can use different search engine like solr, whoosh ...;

You can also use your database Full Text search without using a third library something like [this](http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/news/article/django-full-text-search/).

**EDIT:**
from the OP comment, the QuerySet API offer a full text search feature that work only with MySQL check [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search).

Comment: so after a few tries Djapian and Sphinx doesn't work get stuck in both .... will try whoosh now..

Comment: @Jorge Machado: yes it's not trivial to set a full text engine, i remember the first time when i wanted to use a full text search engine with one of my django project it take me sometime too to make them work , actually i have tried haystask, whoosh , Djapian and the last one was the only one that i was able to set up, :) , Hope you can do better than me :)

Comment: with Djapian i'm getting a wired error that it says it can't find xapian, i'will now try whoosh hope it works...

Comment: @singularity: so i didn't install anything, I use the search option in django queries. it resolves most of my problems. 
Like this local =   Local.objects.filter(name__search=request.GET['descricao'])

Comment: @Jorge Machado: yes true, if you are using MySQL this will give you the full text search feature, i will add it to my answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in non-ascii search and the `icontains` fulfills your needs, i would use a simpler approach of normalizing *ONLY* the unicode characters with diacritics(accents).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unicodedata
def strip_accents( text, encoding='ASCII'):
    return ''.join(
        (c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', unicode(text))
        if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn') )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print strip_accents( u"Corrão quê a polícia vem aí! Será ¿")
    print strip_accents( u"Wie spricht man diessen Wörter aus?" )
```

This obviously means that you should strip the accents on saving/updating operations to maintain the consistency. Which is a sad thing, your text will lose all the appeal of accents... forever!