# Django admin search by treating latin letters like lithuanian letters

Tags: mysql, django, unicode

There are some non-latin letters in lithuanian language and all of them can be written as latin:

ą - a, č - c, ę/ė - e, į - i, š - s, ų/ū - u, ž - z.

For example there are records `ąžuolas` and `azuolas` in the database. If I type query in django admin `ąžuolas` then it finds both records. If `azuolas` - only the second one.

What do I have to change in django (or MySQL) to make it work both ways?

Comment: MySQL's `utf8_lithuanian_ci` collation will probably come in handy.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you tell us the character set of the column you're searching, and give the queries you've tried? Does something like `WHERE _utf8 'azuolas' COLLATE utf8_lithuanian_ci = mycolumn` work?

Comment: It is `utf8_lithuanian_ci` and your given query doesn't work. I haven't tried any custom queries since I use django admin standard search box behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I just learned those characters that look like latin have a generic name: [Diacritic characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)!

Seems that [Django allows this type of query using full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search) (it was documented to be successful in [this comment on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527983/django-queries-especial-caracters#comment4974516_4528115)

**Woooa, check out [this little switch here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L351)!!**

```
elif field_name.startswith('@'):
    return "%s__search" % field_name[1:]
```

Could it be that by searching for `@azuolas` you will finally find `ąžuolas` ? Please give it a try and report on your findings.

Also, here's the related [MySQL article on BOOLEAN MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: Good finding and it would seem to work, however, my tables run on innodb engine and I cannot change it because of error `ERROR 1217: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`. Any ideas how can I work around this?

Comment: I'm not an expert but are you sure that FULLTEXT search is limited to MyISAM  or whatever? Any references? What are you trying to accomplish? If this is unrelated, please post a new question (after searching for a dupe) and link it here, maybe the SO community can help out?

Comment: I found out that FULLTEXT used to be for MyISAM only, however, the situation changed in the mysql 5.6 release and fulltext now works in innodb too. I will try to update my libraries and post results here.